# lldb crashlog - substring not found

Tags: python, xcode, lldb

I want to export my crash from Xcode to file. I've created at desktop file crash.log but I have an error when I'm trying to export file.

```
crashlog -c ~/Desktop/crash.log
```

Error:

```
error: python exception: substring not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your crashlog start with the following banner by any chance?

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------
```

If so, then you're dealing with the new JSON crashlog format. Nobody wants to read the raw JSON, so Xcode.app and Console.app are showing you a textual, user-readable version of the crash, even though the actual file contains just JSON. The textual representation of crashlog you're seeing is not exactly same as the old textual crashlog format and therefore LLDB doesn't know how to parse it. That means you cannot copy/paste it into a file and symbolicate it in LLDB.

As I mentioned before, even though Xcode and Console are showing you a textual representation, the real file is just plain JSON. If you don't believe me, try opening the file with TextEdit.

LLDB is fully capable of parsing the new JSON format. So if you pass the crashlog file to LLDB, it will be able to parse it. Alternatively, if you  must, you can look for the "Full Report" banner  and copy all the JSON below it into a file and pass that into LLDB.

```
-----------
Full Report
-----------
```